# How to analyze the AsyncSocket readDataToLength to a corresponding Wireshark TCP packet?

Tags: ios, tcp, wireshark, asyncsocket, packet-sniffers

For example I have a `AsyncSocket *sock`, and I tried to do a socket read:

```
[sock readDataToLength:BUFFER_SIZE withTimeout:_timeout tag:0];
```

On the other hand, I have do a `Wireshark sniffer` for this network.
How do I figure out this socket read operation is corresponding to which `Wireshark TCP packet`?
Any idea is appreciated!

Or it's not possible to know which TCP packet is corresponding to this socket read operation.
 Because it's two different things.
 Operation system has kept receiving data from network, and the socket read operation is just to read the desired buffer size from the OS's buffer.
 Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using time stamps on the frames coming in on the socket and matching that to frame.time in wireshark?

Comment: thanks, but actually i am sniffering a streaming data. Lots of packets was captured at a very short time.